# Calculate the number of extremities for $f(x)=\frac{(|x|-1)\cdot (|x|-2)}{(|x|-3)(|x|-4)}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions

I understand that graphing $g(x) = \frac{(x-1)\cdot (x-2)}{(x-3)(x-4)}$, for $x>0$ is enough to solve the question. So I require assistance in graphing g(x).
I have tried graphing f(x), but it was incomplete, I could get the following information:

1. roots of $g(x)$ are $2,3$
2. $\lim_{x\to 3^+} g(x) = - \infty$,
   $\lim_{x\to 3^-} g(x) = +\infty$,
   $\lim_{x\to 4^+} g(x) = +\infty$,
   $\lim_{x\to 4^-} g(x) = - \infty$,
   $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = 1$

Without calculating the derivative and equating it to zero, is it possible to guess/calculate the points of extremas?
Since even if I guess that there must be just 1 extrema between $x=1$ and $x=2$, I still wasn't able to get the information of this "hidden" extrema ($x=3.366$):
[image]

I was avoiding to try to calculate the derivative and equating it to zero, because it seemed tiresome, and I would like the quickest solution available to this.

Comment: What do you mean "solve the question"? The question does not ask you for a solution. Also, what do you mean by "extremities"?

Comment: "extrema" perhaps?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have tried graphing f(x), but it was incomplete"?

Comment: by extrema/extremities, I mean the stationary points @ShyamalSayak

Comment: @jjagmath As in, I wasn't able to "completely" graph the equation. Only some parts, which i was sure about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that $f(x)=g(|x|)$. If you can determine the stationary points of $g(x)$ then it is straightforward to deduce those of $f(x)$ by applying the modulus transformation as follows:

Given the graph of $g(x)$, erase all the graph for $x<0$ and reflect the graph of $g(x)$ for $x\geq0$ in the $y$ axis to obtain the entire graph of $g(|x|)$.

To find the stationary points of $g(x)$ without using calculus, set $$y=g(x)=\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{(x-3)(x-4)}$$

Now rearrange this to form a quadratic in $x$, and you get $$(y-1)x^2+x(3-7y)+(12y-2)=0$$

For real $x$, the range of values of $y$ is determined by the discriminant of this quadratic, which must be greater than or equal to zero.

This leads to the inequality $$y^2+14y+1\geq0$$ with critical values $$y=-7\pm4\sqrt{3}$$

You can get the corresponding $x$ values by applying $$x=-\frac{b}{2a}=-\frac{3-7y}{2(y-1)}$$

Hereby you can obtain the exact coordinates of all the stationary points of $f(x)$

PS note that $-7-4\sqrt{3}=-13.92820323…$

Comment: could you elaborate on why the stationary points must lie on the points where  discriminant of the equation $(y−1)x^2+x(3−7y)+(12y−2)=0$ is $0$.

Comment: Also do you mean $x=- \frac{b}{2a}$?

Comment: Yes I do mean $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$. Edited accordingly. The range of possible $y$ values is determined by the fact that $x$ is real. The critical values for $y$ obtained by setting the discriminant $\geq0$ are the same values as obtained by setting the discriminant $=0$. The use of the quadratic discriminant presupposes $y\neq1$ and of course this corresponds to the horizontal asymptote.

Comment: I don't understand why the y coordinates satisfying $y^2+14y+1=0$ would refer to the points which we get when  function g(x) applied on  stationary points of the function $g(x)$. (what i mean by  function g(x) applied on  stationary points is that if $ x_1,x_2$ are stationary points then why would the $y$ coordinates  which we get by setting the  discriminant to $ 0$  satisfy $g(x_1),g(x_2)$.)

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you’re asking

Comment: I mean, you wrote $x=\frac{-b}{2a}=-\frac{3-7y}{2(y-1)}$, and  then put the critical values of $ y $ which you get from  inequality  $y^2+14y+1 \geq 0$, and for these critical values of y placed in that equation,  $ x $ would be a stationary point. Why is this so? Also I only know that for  the parabola $ax^2+bx+c$, the x coordinate of the vertex  would be $\frac{-b}{2a}$, can you replace $b$ and $a $ with any function? ( which you did here). Is there some article/theory behind the method you used to solve the question which I can read for further context?

Comment: When the discriminant of the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is zero, the solution for $x$ is given by $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$. This comes from the quadratic formula. In this case, $a,b$ and $c$ are functions of $y$

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need some variation of the derivative.

For a small $\delta$, find $x$ so that $[g(x+\delta/2)-g(x)][g(x)-g(x-\delta/2)]$

$=g(x+\delta/2)g(x)-g(x+\delta/2)g(x-\delta/2)-g(x)^2+g(x)g(x-\delta/2)<0$

That should help you find where the derivative changes sign, roughly equivalent to where it is $0$. You might be able to use some inequalities to hone in on $x$.

The smaller your $\delta$ the more accurate your $x$.